# Google Drive file etag in v3

Tags: http-headers, google-drive-api, etag

I don't see ETag in [Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource). What to use for "if-match" header to detect conflict in v3?

Comment: I suggest try using it in the same way as the v2 api

Comment: @pinoyyid can you provide an example?

Comment: As @pinoyyid stated, you can use it the same way with [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration). However, I read in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/7FHS5n7DOuI;context-place=forum/drive) that it seems that etag is not applicable for V3. When the developer in that thread tried `fields=etag` as query param, there was an error `Invalid field selection etag`,